# Form Input to Database (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to put a question(text) into my database. The table is put into the database with the ID and time of creating it, but the question(text) is still empty.

(don't notice the Question1/2/3/4, these are not made into the database yet, so it is just about the "Quiz Name")

Here is my code :

```
 public function postCreate() {

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Quiz::$rules);

    if($validator->passes()) {
        $quiz = new Quiz;
        $quiz->quizname = Input::get('quizname');
        $quiz->save();
        return Redirect::to('quizzes')->with('message', 'Your quiz has been created!');
    }
```

---

```
 {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'quizzes/create', 'class' => 'createquiz')) }}
    <h2>Create a Quiz now!</h2>
    <p>Quiz Name</p>{{ Form::text('quizname', null, array('required')) }}
    <p>Question 1</p>{{ Form::text('quizname', null, array('placeholder' => 'Question 1', 'size' => '40')) }}
    <p>Question 2</p>{{ Form::text('quizname', null, array('placeholder' => 'Question 2', 'size' => '40')) }}
    <p>Question 3</p>{{ Form::text('quizname', null, array('placeholder' => 'Question 3', 'size' => '40')) }}
    <p>Question 4</p>{{ Form::text('quizname', null, array('placeholder' => 'Question 4', 'size' => '40')) }}
    <br>
    <br>
    {{ Form::button('Add Question') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Create') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

---

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('quizzes', function($table)
    {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('quizname');
    $table->date('created_at');
    $table->dateTime('updated_at');
    });

    Schema::table('quizzes', function($table)
    {

    });
}
```

Comment: use var_dump(Input::get('quizname')); to see if you are getting the input. If thats empty, thats the stem of your problem. It is most likely related to what @user3158900 mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your inputs should have different names.  The problem is because you are naming everything `quizname`.  I'd suggest giving your questions the name `question[]` so that you can loop through them and easily create them later.